# How to write a Kibana query using regex on it?

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, kibana

Hi thhis is my first time working with kibana. I am creating a simple kibana dashboard for my java application. I have 3 endpoints and in my kibana dashboard, I will create panels to store 5xx and 4xx status code from my application.

My issue is that if I have a path variable in my url, how would my kibana query look like?
I am writing it this way and it does not work (doesn't fetch any results):

```
kubernetes.container_name: "v1/myapp" AND uri: "v1/deposits/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/output"
```

Please help me to rewrite the regex portion.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to click "Edit Query DSL" and there you can use [this regex query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html).

Hope it helps!